# TSQL - Parameters and dynamic table names

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please see the DDL below:

```
CREATE TABLE Person (ID int identity, Name varchar(30), primary key(ID))
INSERT INTO Person (Name) VALUES ('Ian')
```

Please see the TSQL below:

```
Declare @ID int
Declare @Name varchar(30)
set @Name = 'Ian'
select @ID=ID FROM Person WHERE Name=@Name
Print @ID
```

This works as I would expect i.e. 1 is printed to the screen.  I want to make a change so that the table name is dynamic i.e.

```
Declare @ID int
Declare @Name varchar(30)
Declare @TableName as varchar(30)
set @TableName= 'Person'
set @Name = 'Ian'
select @ID=ID FROM @TableName WHERE Name=@Name
Print @ID
```

The above SQL obviously does not work.  I realise that I have to use TSQL.  I have tried using EXEC and sp_executesql, but I can only get part way there.  How do I implement this.  The SQL statement must be: `select @ID=ID FROM @TableName WHERE Name=@Name`.

Comment: create a string variable to build the query, then use sp_executesql on that variable.

Comment: Read this: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Common_cases

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use dynamic sql for this. Have a look here...

```
Declare @ID int
Declare @Name varchar(30)
Declare @TableName sysname
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);


set @TableName= 'Person'
set @Name = 'Ian'

SET @Sql = N'select @ID = ID FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) 
         + N' WHERE Name = @Name'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
                     ,N'@ID int OUTPUT, @Name varchar(30)' 
                     ,@ID OUTPUT
                     ,@Name
PRINT @ID
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks what i am after. I will now test. +1.